# read from app.config instead of dll.config

Tags: c#, console-application, app-config

I have simple console application. In application there is app.config and i have defined few settings which i fetch using ConfigurationManager class like below

```
 var setting = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[key]
```

This works ok when i am debugging on local env. Now when i deploy this code to develepment server then it reads setting from dll.config instead of app.config.
I tried to google but i am not able to find any clue.

Is it possible to change behaviour to read from app.config always? The reason i am asking is because i have added transformation for app.config. So for Dev server its called app.DevServer.config and it has some specific settings.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can manually read your app.config file with code like this:

```
    var configMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap { ExeConfigFilename = "app.DevServer.config" };
    var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(configMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None, true);
    var setting = config.AppSettings.Settings[key];
```

Comment: But when the code is deployed then app,config is deployed and not app.devserver.config. I cannot write hardcoded name like app.devserver.config

Comment: So can't you write "app.config" as the name then? I don't think I understand what's happening.

Comment: it reads app.config from some wiered path and not from where my current project is located . it reads from C:\\Users\\MyUser\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\lp51yg0m.gbo\\2v0j3vt4.4t2\\App.config

Comment: You can specify a full path for `ExeConfigFilename`. You might be able to get it from something like the `Location` or `CodeBase` property of `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()` (if this is an EXE).